# How to write numpy where condition based on indices and not values?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array and I need to extract all elements `array[i][j]` if the conditions

`x1range < i < x2range` and `y1range < j < y2range` are satisfied.

How do I write such conditions? Do I need to use mgrid/ogrid?

Edit: Should have written my additional requirement. I was looking for a where condition, and not splicing, because I want to change the values of all the elements to (0,0,0) which satisfy the above condition. I assumed if I have a where condition, I could do that.

Edit2: Also, is it possible to get the 'not' of the above condition?

As in,

```
if i > x1range and i < x2range and j > y1range and j < y2range: # the above condition
    do nothing # keep original value
else:
    val = (0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem #1: Getting indices within the range**

You could use [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to get those indices -

```
In [145]: x1range,x2range = 2,5
     ...: y1range,y2range = 1,4
     ...: 

In [146]: np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1range,x2range),np.arange(y1range,y2range))
Out[146]: 
[array([[2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4]]), array([[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]])]
```

**Problem #2 : Extracting or setting input array elements within those ranges**

You could use [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to directly index into the input array `arr` -

```
In [148]: arr
Out[148]: 
array([[97, 69,  0, 60, 28, 97],
       [98, 85, 24, 75, 97, 23],
       [70, 25, 77, 86, 93, 66],
       [ 0, 85, 51, 17, 40, 92],
       [66, 28, 28, 22, 79, 52]])

In [149]: arr[np.ix_(np.arange(x1range,x2range),np.arange(y1range,y2range))]
Out[149]: 
array([[25, 77, 86],
       [85, 51, 17],
       [28, 28, 22]])
```

With this indexing, one can also set all those elements directly.

**Problem #3 : Extracting or setting input array elements NOT within those ranges**

To set/ extract the `not` satisfied elements to `0s` and keeping rest as the same, you can use [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) alongwith `boolean-indexing` like so -

```
In [150]: Imask = np.in1d(np.arange(arr.shape[0]),np.arange(x1range,x2range))
     ...: Jmask = np.in1d(np.arange(arr.shape[1]),np.arange(y1range,y2range))
     ...: arr[~(Imask[:,None] & Jmask)] = 0
     ...: 

In [151]: arr
Out[151]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 25, 77, 86,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 85, 51, 17,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 28, 28, 22,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: Hi, I will try this. And just an additional question, what if I want to reverse this query? Is that possible? As in, the 'not' of this condition?

Comment: @n00b Could you edit the question with a sample as to what you mean by "not" of this condition?

Answer (score 0):

just a guess.

```
x=array[x1range:x2range,y1range:y2range]
```

Comment: Why does this code work? Could you please add some context it your answer?

Answer (score 0):

What about slicing?

```
array[x1range:x2range,y1range:y2range]
```

Example:

```
numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])[0:2,0:2]
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])
```

Comment: Hi, I added an additional requirement. Sorry for not mentioning it earlier. I was looking for a where condition so I can change the values of all elements which satisfy the given condition.